# How can I use JSDoc custom types across files in my sveltekit project?

Tags: typescript, jsdoc

I'm encountering a problem when using JSDoc with custom types in a SvelteKit project. Specifically, when I use the syntax (import('$lib/types').CustomType) in my JSDoc comments, VSCode's linting recognizes it without any issues. However, this approach leads to a complication during the documentation compilation process.

When I attempt to generate documentation, I receive the following error:

`Unable to parse a tag's type expression for source file "my-path" in line 11 with tag title "returns" and text "{(Day | number)[][]} - Array of week arrays, each containing Day objects or numbers.": Invalid type expression "(Day | number)[][]": Expected "!", "=", "?", or end of input but "[" found.`

For context, my custom types are defined in a types.d.ts file. I'm generally pleased with JSDoc's capabilities, but it seems that importing custom types is somewhat problematic. I'm wondering if there's a different approach or workaround to handle custom type imports in JSDoc effectively. Any suggestions or insights from the community would be greatly appreciated.